# Convert between coordinate spaces

Tags: ios, math, rotation, linear-algebra, gyroscope

I'm trying to simulate a realistic camera in OpenGL ES, using iPhone camera and data received from gyroscope sensor. Basically when I receive roll, pitch and yaw rotation from gyroscope I pass them to the openGL context and rotate every object in scene by minus of each angle, simulating the camera rotate.

```
CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix]; // cocos3D matrix 

[modelView populateFromRotation:CC3VectorMake(-pitch, -roll, -yaw)];
[modelView translateBy:CC3VectorMake(0, 0, -distance)];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);
```

And it works just fine. The problem is that iPhone coordinate system rotates with the phone, so for example roll is always "hitting" the sides of the phone. So when I add another object, alpha degrees to the left/right, it becomes the left/right of the iPhone coordinate system, not the world coordinate system.

The first image is with no rotation, looking ahead.
[image]

But when I rotate the phone to the right by around 30-40 degrees, it becomes obvious that the objects' sides are no longer parallel.

[image]
The rotation of the second object:

```
CC3GLMatrix *modelView2 = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
[modelView2 populateFromRotation:CC3VectorMake(-pitch, -roll-30, -yaw)];
[modelView2 translateBy:CC3VectorMake(0, 0, -distance)];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView2.glMatrix);
```

As the phone is inclined to the right, so are the objects, and the only difference in objects positions is -30 in roll, meaning coordinate system is bound to the phone and rotates with the phone.

Is there a way to convert these coordinates to the world coordinates or any other way to rotate the whole scene in real world?

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar with Objective C but it seams you are doing the transformations in reverse order.
If you want to translate (matrix T) and then rotate (matrix R) the vertex v, in OpenGL, you need to do R*T*v; so the modelView = R*T;